# What do you call a word that is broken onto two lines?

Tags: punctuation, names

For example, the word "recreated" fell at the end of the a line, and thus was printed as:

```
re-

created
```

Is there a special name for this sort of thing?

Comment: It’s been *hyphenated*

Comment: It entered a line break in the wrong place.

Comment: Yeah, *poorly* hyphenated.  (There are very few situations where it would be necessary to hyphenate a word and only split off two characters.  Far better to keep the word together.  I learned this about the 3rd day in typing class.)

Comment: Hot Licks is right there - although that's a modern view and vintage books are often full of splits like that.

'Bad break' is a group term which happen to include that problem, which doesn't have its own specific name. I learned both during a generation in publishing.

Answer (score 1):

During pagination, such breaks are known as **bad breaks**. A bad break occurs when a line is not able to accommodate the entire word, and breaks it and makes it run on the next line. In your example, there could be instances where this hyphen (bad) break could be misleading. Check out some examples at: 
http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/hyphens/hyphens-with-the-prefix-re/

Proofreaders are required to check such instances of breaks, and mark them for correction. 
The Chicago Manual describes these breaks at length.

See **Index W > proofreading for bad breaks**

http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/search.epl?entqr=0&access=p&output=xml_no_dtd&sort=date%3AD%3AL%3Ad1&ie=UTF-8&client=live&q=proofreading&filter=0&search_edition=16&ud=1&site=cms16dev&oe=UTF-8&proxystylesheet=cmosdev&ip=172.16.2.120&proxyreload=1&start=170

Hope it helps!